# Using same Apple ID with two of our phones, can they be linked

Tags: macos, ipad, iphone

My boyfriend and I are using the same Apple ID on both of our phones. I just want know how can I link my phone to his?

Comment: I want to get massages that he get and want to see call log

Comment: I want to get the massges the he recives and his log.Is there is any way to get that?

Comment: This sounds less like a technical problem, and more like a relationship problem.

Answer (score 1):

Without jailbreak no.

Even if you're using the same Apple ID on both devices, you can't get the same SMS and call (and also call logs) of the other device, because this two things depends from the telephone number and they're recorded on the device that received the message / call.

Probably you'll get the iMessage on both devices because they works differently, so every device logged with the same ID will get all the messages, but deletion are not synchronized.

Apple ID is used to keep settings, app and profile settings synced across Apple devices.